# Shopify background-image with css (doesn't show)

Tags: shopify

My problem is that when trying to insert some kind of a background image in Shopify, it never shows anything.

I have a navigation bar that has a pattern which the client wants and when I try to enable it, again nothing happens.

The code I'm using on that css background line (from googling around) is

```
background:url( "{{'navBggreen.jpg' | asset_url }}")
```

I've also tried

```
background:url( {{'navBggreen.jpg' | asset_url }} )
```

and nothing. Tutorials or any kind of documentation is extremely scarce for Shopify so...

Anyway, does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call it like this from your CSS file in Assets:

```
.nav{background: url("navBggreen.jpg");}
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. You should include using asset_url, that's how shopify works. And as Ruchi mentioned, make sure the file extension is liquid.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your css file has .liquid extension so that it can process liquid code as asset_url is part of liquid. so make sure, your css file name is something like style.css.liquid.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to include images in your layout you will have to use the `asset_url` filter. However, if your images are called via a CSS stylesheet then you do not need to use `asset_url` - except if they are used in a theme settings form. Take out the `asset_url` and it should work ok.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, so if am calling it via CSS external stylesheet(which i am) then how do i call to it? Thanks in advanced